# Where can I obtain Autohotkey.dll library to run Pyahk?

Tags: python, dll, autohotkey

[Pyahk documentation](http://pyahk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) says:

> A copy of the ANSI 32-bit dll must be provided either in the system location of your version of Windows, or in the same folder as the ahk.py file. (The required dll is not provided as part of this distribution, see the [AutoHotKey.dll](http://www.autohotkey.net/~HotKeyIt/AutoHotkey/files/AutoHotkey-dll-txt.html) site for download instructions (alternate link [AutoHotKey_H](http://hotkeyit.ahk4.net/files/AutoHotkey-txt.html)).)

Autohotkey.dll site does not provide any download instructions. The alternate link does not work.

I found some dlls [here](https://hotkeyit.github.io/v2). Pyahk is not able to import the 32bit dll versions. I'm able to import ahk in python without the missing dll warning with the 64bit dll, but upon a call the library complains about some chinese characters.

[image]

Possibly I need to compile autohotkey.dll myself. If so I would prefer a method which does not require me to install a ton of compilation tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the source code here: https://github.com/HotKeyIt/ahkdll
And the releases can be found here: https://github.com/HotKeyIt/ahkdll-v1-release

You'll find a couple of different versions (unicode, ansi, 64 bit, 32 bit ...).